# Django Forms self.fields for Foreign Keys and Session Values?

Tags: python, django

I have a form where I'm trying to add initial value to hidden filed from a `session`.

When I use

```
self.fields['myfield'] = forms.CharField(initial=request.session['value'])
```

the session value is correctly rendered but I do get error:

```
Cannot assign "u'123'": "Model.filed" must be a "Model" instance.
```

I know the error is because it is a foreign key field.

When I do

```
myfield = forms.CharField(initial=request.session['value'])
```

the form is working without errors but the `request.session['value']` is not rendered and the initial value is empty.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure the `123` (or whatever) is a valid primary key for your model referenced in the `ForeignKey` field.

You could prevent that in the place where you're adding the `value` item to the `session` dict.

Now, the `initial` argument is looking for a valid object, so just give it that.

```
self.fields['myfield'] = forms.CharField(
    initial=MyOtherModel.objects.get(pk=request.session['value'])
)
```

Note: I'm supposing `MyOtherModel` is the `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. It seems to be working, however when I render the hidden field in my template the initial value is a name field of the model in stead of the `PK`. Any suggestions how to render the ID/PK?

Comment: Django uses the value returned by the `__str__()` method defined in the model to show it in the form, so just alter that method and return the `self.pk`.

Comment: something like: `def __str__(self): return str(self.pk)` with their respective indentation should works

Comment: Excellent, that seems to work, I guess now I have to check for other errors as I did have `def __unicode__(self): return u'%s' % (self.name)` in that model. Any ways to have both? the `unicode` for name and the `str()`?

Comment: Ohh, use `__unicode__(self)` when python 2, `__str__(self)` on python 3k

Comment: The `__str__(self)` is working OK but I know that I'm using the `name` field elsewhere and I'm not sure if I can have both, the `pk` and `name` as when I have both in place, the `initial` value is still returning the `name` field. What I meant is if I can somehow tell the form to use the `str` in stead of the `name` field.

Comment: http://arunrocks.com/python-3-cheatsheet-for-djangonauts/#change-all-9595unicode9595-methods-into-9595str9595